# Can I use d3.js to draw the graph using json string or json object?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I've just started a task on d3.js, I have changed a little of this script online, please see the last below.

Currently the last below part could work for reading a local file, while currently I have my own json object returned from ajax, which is processed by the backend.

```
success function(data){ }
```

So could I please ask if in this case, how could I use d3.json? As the below part could just worked for reading the data from json file, but not from a json string or json object.
Is there a possible function provided to replace the

> d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {   if (error) throw
>   error; ... }

As this could only process the file, but not the input json string or object?

```
d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var link = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      /*.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); })*/;

  var node = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "nodes")
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("r", 3)
      /*.attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })*/
      .call(d3.drag()
          .on("start", dragstarted)
          .on("drag", dragged)
          .on("end", dragended));

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

  simulation
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
      .links(graph.links);

  function ticked() {
    link
        .attr("x1", function(d) { return (d.source.x); })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return (d.source.y); })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return (d.target.x); })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return (d.target.y); });

    node
        .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  }
});
```

my json object is like

```
{"nodes": [
    {"id": "Myriel"},
    {"id": "Napoleon"},
    {"id": "Mlle.Baptistine"},
    {"id": "Mme.Magloire"},
    {"id": "CountessdeLo"},
    {"id": "Geborand"},
    {"id": "Champtercier"},
    {"id": "Cravatte"},
    {"id": "Count"},
    {"id": "OldMan"},
    {"id": "Labarre"},
    {"id": "Valjean"},
    {"id": "Marguerite"},
    {"id": "Mme.deR"}
]}
```

ThQ!!!!

Comment: How is this different from your other question [*"Can I process a string which is like a json format using d3.json?"*](/q/51075086)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No d3.json will not accept a object, it requires a filepath (docs https://github.com/d3/d3-fetch/blob/master/README.md#json).

However, I dont think you need d3.json, you can just use JSON.parse on the data and proceed.

```
success function(data){ var graph = JSON.parse(data) ...}
```